# Writing Spock test to verify method invocation in async method

Tags: java, unit-testing, asynchronous, spock

If I have a standard method like this:

```
private MessageReceiver getMessageReceiver() {
    method1();
}
```

In Spock, I can test the number of calls like this:

```
1 * method1();
```

But in my case the method looks like this (used to received pubsub messages)

```
private MessageReceiver getMessageReceiver() {
    return (message, consumer) -> {
        method1();
    }
}
```

How can I write a Spock test to do the same as before and verify that method1 was called one time?

Comment: Could you please share more of your code, otherwise we can only give really vague answers, like you need to observe what happens in method two and assert on that.

Comment: Sure, I updated my question for better clarity

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Leonard that it is your job to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Today is your lucky day, however, and I had some time to play around and speculate about your situation, which I think is as follows:

```java
interface MessageReceiver {
  def process(def message, def consumer)
}
```

```java
class UnderTest {
  def doSomething() {
    Thread.start { getMessageReceiver().process("message", "consumer") }
  }

  private MessageReceiver getMessageReceiver() {
    return { message, consumer ->
      method1()
    }
  }

  def method1() {
    sleep 500
    println "Doing something"
  }
}
```

Please note that I am using a Groovy closure here instead of a Java lambda in order to make the code compatible with Groovy versions < 4.

Spock has built-in support for testing asynchronous code. Unfortunately, the Spock manual does not cover `AsyncConditions`, `BlockingVariable` and `BlockingVariables` at all and only mentions [`PollingConditions`](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.2-M2/all_in_one.html#_polling_conditions) as part of the old 0.7 release notes from 2012 in passing. You need to experiment with those classes or check Spock's internal tests in order to find out more about them. In this case, I am showing you a polling conditions variant:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q72958882

import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.util.concurrent.PollingConditions

class AsyncMethodTest extends Specification {
  def "my feature"() {
    given:
    int timesExecuted
    // In order to verify interactions on self-invoked methods of a class under
    // test, we need a spy.
    UnderTest underTest = Spy() {
      method1() >> {
        // On the one hand, we need to stub this method in order to increment a
        // counter which can then be checked in the polling condition. On the
        // other hand, we  need to call the real method in order to make the
        // class under test behave normally.
        callRealMethod()
        timesExecuted++
      }
    }

    when:
    underTest.doSomething()

    then:
    new PollingConditions(timeout: 1).eventually {
      timesExecuted == 1
    }
  }
}
```

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJxtU8lu2zAQvesrBjpZiKPEAYK6AWygaHvoIWiR5Vww1MgiTJEqFztGkH_vkKIk24kOEjUzfPPeLB3jW7ZBqLC03Pj2b8usQ1NaRw69Q1NLvS__fbn5ertcLm-yTLSdNg5sp_m2lExtyscOuagFZ05oder3TsiSa8W9Mahc-UdLKdTmu1aVCNE2y7hk1sI3e1D8Hl2jqye0DvDVoaosnGDDWwZEtIa8PUCNzHmD-ayIZoCN2KG6i0ehHDjRov35itw7rKL16gp-KdCmQgNOA2kT9SHEomE8sgHKYVHWl0Lt9BYraCMjstfAoGfqFd0f8BxxncMeQSFFM1J9KKPvOURFJX48rUjNYaQLCXxBlvV6NEbY3wpcg8QGoWGqmjIQbev8C3mFTfdJwKRJKG6wpUoDO8bj2geVsG8Eb4CzCK_gBYE3yINQ0Wfs-v7QhdSgMnE5RtP0byZiIzPOpIwoBpn8jF3LtngOdlTUWE0i1bAdydWmJbxUzvAE-AdC7qdkVoyOk05fXCT7e9a_42ffDKMxtqOs9KMOJEkvgUWnG8MU7uHDsM5CJu3dHSyKEmnanA8Ux96dEIHVChbZwOQ9IyZx1GrGEe7RWtq6B-RIU2vGwe6M5uSahXPbx8yjgxpifYumCDh9zaYRG26fKEqsnhrqRhXWmZbyDTboznLPinLImqeU-RzyIWFeJP706ozYMfeR_WegKb1BWlJa3EnNAAyX6_M9OKpWUjStSA9nJWIHt9fX8Y_4KCcV5D90GFo7iM9Twf8DDjaONg).

**Update:** Of course, you can omit `callRealMethod()`, if the real method is very slow and you want to speed up the test, using a very short polling condition.

Comment: The `PollingConditions` methods `eventually` and `within` are annotated with `@ConditionBlock`, so they also get transformed into implicit conditions. That means the explicit `assert` is not necessary. The caveat is that it only works if Spock can determine at compile time, that the type of the object is actually `PollingConditions`, that is why it doesn't work if the variable is defined with `def`. And it only works if it is called inside a `Specification` otherwise you need the explicit `assert`.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the helpful hints.,  But like I said, those valuable classes should all be covered in the Spock manual. Then I would not need to copy suboptimal sample code using `def` from a now outdated example in old release notes.

Comment: FYI, I have updated the polling condition - which is created in place and thus type-safe, because I inlined the variable using `def` in my first local version before posting here anyway - to use a Spock condition instead of an explicit assertion, according to Leonard's recommendation. The GWC link has been updated, too.

Comment: Another thing, for the scenario you are describing, which might matches OP scenario or not, you could/should use a `CountDownLatch` instead of `PollingConditions`. Set it up with one counter, do the countdown in the mock and await (with timeout) in the `then` block.